# Add zero padding to numbers with fmt.Printf

Tags: go, printf

I have a question about the function fmt.Printf;
Why when I use this functions, the program omits the first zero?

```
package main

import (
   "fmt"
   "time"
)

func main() {
   now := time.Now()
   year, month, day := now.Date()
   hour, min, sec := now.Clock()
   fmt.Printf("%d-%s-%d_%d:%d:%d\n", year, month, day, hour, min, sec)
}
```

That returns: 2017-April-26_10:3:2 at 10h03:02

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply replace `%d` with `%02d` i.e.

```
fmt.Printf("%d-%s-%02d_%02d:%02d:%02d\n", year, month, day, hour, min, sec)
```